# How to read QR codes without Securing Margin(quiet zone)?

Tags: decode, qr-code, zxing

As I know, standard QR code has securing margin.But I found that many tools that create QR codes without securing margin. And if these QR codes put into dark background, they can't be decoded by many decoders, including zxing QR code decoder. But I did found one QR code decoder can decoder them. I am so curious and I tried to figure out how they do that. I get stuck now. So can anybody help me, give me an idea or a hint?I would appreciate that. 
here is a QR code without securing margin.

[image]

Comment: programatically? Which language?

Comment: You could locate the code (this is fairly easy for a human), add a white background and run the reader.

Comment: Humans are absolutely great at detecting patterns. (So much so we often detect patterns that don't exist.) It's a lot harder to do the same thing in code. If you know exactly the kind of non-conforming distortion to expect, it's often not hard to compensate for it. (Don't know if that's the OP's case.) The trouble is, if you're trying to compensate for an unbounded set of distortions, it's very hard to compensate: the heuristics start to interact, e.g., the heuristic that makes one example decode makes another fail. Be nice if the people implementing qr codes understood this.

Answer (score 1):

What those programs do exactly is hard to tell unless you ask their authors directly, but what they may probably be doing is locking onto the inner black squares inside the three corners, instead of locking onto the outsides of the outer borders of those corners. While the outside white border is only fully white when the securing margin is present, the inside white border is always white.

Comment: "While the outside white border is only fully white when the securing margin is present, the inside white border is always white.": unless, of course, it's not. Many people distort QR codes in many ways, including colorizing them, using images as data modules, etc. And every heuristic added to a decoder to make one distorted image decode is almost certain to make another image not decode. It's a no-win game if people don't abide by the standard, or to the extent they don't abide by the standard.

Comment: @smparkes: Thing is, those three corners in a QR code is the most vulnerable part of it, so you can sort of count on them being present (it's _much_ harder to lock on the pixels without them). Also, heuristics added to a decoder wouldn't normally make it worse - usually just slower. And while I'm all for people abiding by standards (we all remember Web 1.0 mess), QR codes can be damaged naturally, and that's something any decoder should try to handle as best as possible.

Comment: Many heuristics make decoding worse for other cases. Relavant to this example, zxing uses heuristics to identify the "white" and "black" colors in a code so that it can handle both colorized codes and codes where the brightness varies across the image, e.g., shadows. Both of these heuristics can cause decoding to fail on images that have been arbitrarily colorized in the quiet zone. In general, the zxing authors (which include me) try to make zxing decode standard images that have been damaged. That's a different than images that have been intentionally distorted, which are a lower priority.